# Divide list of dictionary into sub dictionary in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I get 'n' number of records from my database using MySQLdb in list of dictionary. I want to sub divide the list into different sub list depending upon the data. e.g.

```
col1    |   col2    |   col3    |   col4

data11  |   data12  |   data13  |   data14
data11  |   data12  |   data23  |   data24
data11  |   data13  |   data33  |   data34
data11  |   data13  |   data43  |   data44
data21  |   data12  |   data53  |   data54
data21  |   data12  |   data63  |   data64
data21  |   data13  |   data73  |   data74
data21  |   data13  |   data83  |   data84
```

I want to convert this data into:

```
col1    |   col2    |   col3    |   col4
```

1st list:

```
data11  |   data12  |   data13  |   data14
data11  |   data12  |   data23  |   data24
```

2nd list:

```
data11  |   data13  |   data33  |   data34
data11  |   data13  |   data43  |   data44
```

3rd list:

```
data21  |   data12  |   data53  |   data54
data21  |   data12  |   data63  |   data64
```

4th list:

```
data21  |   data13  |   data73  |   data74
data21  |   data13  |   data83  |   data84
```

Is there any super awesome way of Python to group multiple columns and divide list into multiple lists.

EDIT:

Currently, I have:

```
[{ "col1":"data11","col2":"data12","col3":"data13","col4":"data14"
},
...
]
```

I want to sub divide these data into list of dictionary depending on values present in col1 and col2.

You can understand it from the table above. I guess output will be in [[{}]] format.

Comment: So are you wanting to convert list of dictionary into list of lists? Can you update your question with a sample python data structure on how you want to access the output?

Comment: @user3885927 I edited the question as per your request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use dictionaries of dictionaries:

```
super_awesome = {}
for row in rows:    # these are the rows from MySQLdb
    col1 = super_awesome.get(row['col1'], {})    # get col1 or an empty dict
    col2 = col1.get(row['col2'], [])             # get col2 or an empty list
    col2.append(row)                             # append row to (col1,col2)
    col1[row['col2']] = col2                     # put col2 into col1
    super_awesome[row['col1']] = col1            # put col1 into super_awesome
```

When you're done, `super_awesome` has an entry for each unique `col1` value, and each of those entries has an entry for each unique `(col1,col2)` value.  In turn, those entries each have a list of rows for that `(col1,col2)` pair.

Comment: Can I get an output in [[{}]] datatype rather than {{[{}]}} as per your answer?

Comment: I'll leave that up to you.